# Erro: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estou fazendo o curso de Python 3 do curso em vídeo e estou no exercício n° 82.
Mesmo meu código e o do professor sendo quase idênticos, o meu está dando o erro *not all arguments converted during string formatting*.
Meu código é este:

```
a = list()
b = list()
c = list()
while True:
    a.append(input('Digite um número:'))
    r = str(input('Deseja continuar: [S/N]:')).upper().strip()
    if r == 'N':
        break
for i, v in enumerate(a):
    print(v)
    print(i)
    if v % 2 == 0:
        b.append(v)
    elif v % 2 != 0:
        c.append(v)
print(f'A lista de números digitados é: {a}')
print(f'Desses números, {len(b)} deles são pares. Estes são {b}')
print(f'Desses números, {len(c)} deles são impares. Estes são {c}')
```

O PyCharm não aponta nenhum erro. Onde foi que eu errei?
Aliás, minha versão do Python é 3.6
E o erro está acontecendo na linha 12:`if v % 2 == 0:`

Comment: Só um detalhe: o resultado de `numero % 2`, para qualquer número, sempre será 0 ou 1. Então o `elif` é desnecessário, podendo ser trocado por um `else`: `if v % 2 == 0: b.append(v) else: c.append(v)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esse erro ocorre, pois você está tentando utilizar o operador `%` em uma string:

```
if v % 2 == 0:
```

Ao utilizar a função `input` para pegar os dados, essa função retorna uma string, mesmo o usuário digitando um número.

Você pode corrigir isso, convertendo o valor que o usuário digita para um inteiro, utilizando a função `int` no seguinte trecho do código:

```
a.append(int(input('Digite um número:')))
```

---

Como a função `input` já retorna uma string, você pode remover a função `str` no momento que solicita o *S/N* ao usuário:

```
r = input('Deseja continuar: [S/N]:').upper().strip()
```

---

Seu código então ficara mais ou menos da seguinte forma:

```
a = list()
b = list()
c = list()

while True:
    a.append(int(input('Digite um número:')))
    r = input('Deseja continuar: [S/N]:').upper().strip()
    if r == 'N':
        break

for i, v in enumerate(a):
    print(v)
    print(i)
    if v % 2 == 0:
        b.append(v)
    elif v % 2 != 0:
        c.append(v)

print(f'A lista de números digitados é: {a}')
print(f'Desses números, {len(b)} deles são pares. Estes são {b}')
print(f'Desses números, {len(c)} deles são impares. Estes são {c}')
```

> Veja online: https://repl.it/repls/JumpyDishonestLifecycle

---

> Documentações:
>
> https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input
>
> https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int